# Javascript error: object is not a function in a video poker script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have been writing a script to play a video (or really text-based) poker game as an exercise in learning Javascript.  I have everything working to play through an instance of the game once, but on trying to run it a second time, it develops an error: "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"

This error comes up when trying to create a new hand.

Here is the relevant code, I left a few functions out that don't seem to be causing any issues:

```
//object constructor for card
function card(suite, faceValue) {
  this.suite = suite,
  this.faceValue = faceValue
}

//object constructor for hand
function hand(cards, handName, score, docHandName) {
  this.cards = cards,
  this.handName = handName,
  this.score = score,
  this.docHandName = docHandName
}

var deck = new Array;
var buildDeck = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 52; i++) {
    if (i < 13) {
      deck[i] = new card("Spades", i + 2);
    }
    else if (i < 26) {
      deck[i] = new card("Clubs", i - 11);
    }
    else if (i < 39) {
      deck[i] = new card("Hearts", i - 24);
    }
    else if (i < 52) {
      deck[i] = new card("Diamonds", i - 37);
    }
  }
}

//pulls a card from location in deck specified by randomSpot()
var pullCard = function(spot) {
    var newCard = deck[spot];
    deck.splice(spot, 1);
    return newCard;
}

//takes away a card each time
//passes into pullCard(spot) as spot
var pullCount = 0;
var randomSpot = function() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (52 - pullCount));
  pullCount++;
  return x;
}

var dealFiveCards = function() {
  var card1 = pullCard(randomSpot());
  var card2 = pullCard(randomSpot());
  var card3 = pullCard(randomSpot());
  var card4 = pullCard(randomSpot());
  var card5 = pullCard(randomSpot());
  var fiveCards = [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5];
  return fiveCards;
}

function createNewHand() {
  newHand = new hand();
  newHand.cards = dealFiveCards();
  return newHand;
}

var playOneGame = function() {
  buildDeck();
  hand = createNewHand();
  hand.cards.sort(compare);
  assignHandScore();
  wager = prompt("How much do you bet?");
  printHandValue();
  dealAgain();
  hand.cards.sort(compare);
  assignHandScore();
  payout = pays(wager);
  printHandValue();
  printPayout();
}

playAgain = "Y";

while (playAgain === "Y") {
  playOneGame();
  playAgain = prompt("Would you like to play again? Y/N").toUpperCase();
}
```

So the error occurs when trying to run the `playOneGame()` function a second time.  The first time runs fine and a hand is created.  The second time when it gets to `hand = createNewHand();`  it gives the object is not a function error.

To be clear, I have the `hand` created as an object, which contains properties `cards, handName, score, docHandName` where `cards` is an array of `card` objects, themselves containing properties of `suite, faceValue`.

The error gives the line `newHand = new hand();` in function `createNewHand()` as the reference line.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of `playOneGame` is overriding your global `hand` function with an instance of hand. So when `createNewHand` runs again `hand` it is no longer the same thing.

You should probably rename the function `hand` to `Hand`.

Comment: Holy cow batman, changing the object constructor to `Hand` worked! Problem solved.  Until I find a new problem...

Thanks!